# carousel slide is not working, images are not displayed on same row

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, carousel

I tried design a Web Page.
I am using carousel.
The Left and Right options doesn't work, Instead all the images gets added on the Vertical Manner.

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;">Top Visiting Sites</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="row" id="Places">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is what i have used on html.
And this is the Js I have used.

```
for (var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
      var stars = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>';
      var obj = sort[i];
      $('#Places').append(`
      <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right:2px solid gray;">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <div style="background-image: url(/Images/${ obj.Name}.JPG)" class="TourismImage"></div>
          <h4><span> ${ obj.Name}</span></h4>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>                                  
        `); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all of your elements inside of the div with the class="item active". You need to add them to the carousel-inner div, each in a separate div with only the "item" class.

Your end result should look like this :

```
<div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <!-- html of your first item -->
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <!-- html of your second item -->
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <!-- html of your third item -->
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <!-- html of your fourth item -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still see they are getting as two rows

Answer (score 0):

The content inside append function misses the ending quote. Please check that.

```
     $('#Places').append('
  <div class="carousel-item">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right:2px solid gray;">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div style="background-image: url(/Images/${ obj.Name}.JPG)" class="TourismImage"></div>
      <h4><span> ${ obj.Name}</span></h4>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>                                  
    ');
```

Can you try and see whether the above with end quote works?

You should also have your `carousal-inner` class id as `Places` and remove the `class=row` div

```
                <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
                <div class="carousel-inner" id="Places">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Also remove active class as it should be set only on the first item, which you can do separately.

Comment: still same no changes

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I made the change which is suggested.. but i dont see the change